# Preencher tabela com dados da BD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-datatables

Estou com um problema ao adicionar a designação de um artigo através do código. Tenho o seguinte:

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="vendaTabela" width="100%" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-class="expand">Cód.</th>
      <th data-hide="phone">Designação</th>
      <th data-hide="phone">Qnt.</th>
      <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Uni.</th>
      <th>Preço</th>
      <th>Desconto</th>
      <th>IVA</th>
      <th>Sub-Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr id="tr0">
         <td class="codigo" contenteditable="true" onblur="codArtigo ( )"></td>
         <td class="designacao"  contenteditable="true"></td>
         <td class="quantidade"  contenteditable="true"></td>
         <td class="unidade"  contenteditable="true"></td>
         <td class="preco"  contenteditable="true" onblur="subtotal()"></td>
         <td class="desconto"  contenteditable="true"></td>
         <td class="iva"  contenteditable="true"></td>
         <td class="total"  contenteditable="true"></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
codArtigo = function () {
   var $linhas = $("#vendaTabela tbody > tr");
   $linhas.each(function () {
     var designacao = $(".designacao", this).html();
     console.log($(".designacao", this).html());

     myJSRoutes.controllers.ArtigoController.getArtigobyId($(".codigo", this).html()).ajax({
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                            $(".designacao", designacao).html(value.designacaoComercial);
                            console.log(value.designacaoComercial);
                            $(".unidade", $(".unidade", this).html()).html(value.unidade.descricao);
                            console.log(value.unidade.descricao);
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

O que me está a acontecer é o seguinte. Se adiciono o código '1', a tabela preenche a designação com 'exemplo'. Depois se acrescentar outra linha e adicionar outro artigo (código: 2, designação: exemplo2), a designação das duas linhas fica com o nome exemplo2.

Penso que não esteja a conseguir reconhecer o this nesta parte:

```
var designacao = $(".designacao", this).html();
```

PS: Ao fazer o console.log($(".codigo", this).html()), se tiver introduzido dois artigos o output é:

Ao inserir o primeiro:
1

Ao inserir o segundo:
1
2

Alguma sugestão ?

**EDIT:**

Estou com outro problema idêntico e como tal resolvi editar esta pergunta.

```
//REMOVER LINHAS DA TABELA
    $(document).on('click', '#btnDeleteRow', function(){
        var $linhas = $("#vendaTabela tbody > tr");
        $linhas.each(function () {
           var total = $(".total", this);
            $(".totalBruto").html(ttb-(parseFloat(total.html())));
            console.log(total.html());
        })
```

Estou a tentar atualizar o resultado de uma conta que é o totalBruto-totalLinha. o que me acontece é que se eu tiver duas ou mais linhas, este this : `var total = $(".total", this);` parece não me estar a funcionar. O que estarei a falhar ? O `console.log(total.html());` imprime todos os totais e não o da linha que se carrega :s

**PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO:**

Em vez de percorrer as linhas, como estou a utilizar um onclick no botão fui pela linha do botão:  `var total = $(this).closest('tr').find(".total").text();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que você deve está se permendo ao tentar referenciar os variaveis a esmo.

Então reoganizei a declaração das suas variaveis, talvez resolva o seu problema

```
codArtigo = function () {
    var $linhas = $("#vendaTabela tbody > tr");
    $linhas.each(function () {
        var designacao = $(".designacao", this);
        var codigo = $(".codigo", this);
        var unidade = $(".unidade", this);

        console.log(designacao.html());     
        myJSRoutes.controllers.ArtigoController.getArtigobyId(codigo.html()).ajax({
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        designacao.html(value.designacaoComercial);                     
                        unidade.html(value.unidade.descricao);

                        console.log(value.designacaoComercial);
                        console.log(value.unidade.descricao);
                    });
                }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

**P.S: Gostaria de ter postado isto como comentario, mas por causa do Codigo, preferi faze-lo como resposta.**

Comment: De facto foi má organização minha do código. Está perfeitamente funcional. Muito Obrigado :D